# Windows Phone character-encoding

Tags: character-encoding, windows-phone, iso, turkish

My code is `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");` in my Windows Phone project. But "iso-8859-9" is not supported on Windows Phone. How can I fix this problem?

http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator

I also found this link but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the program, just type the encoding name and it will generate the class like so:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/U559Fnv.png]

Then make a file for the class somewhere (Copypaste the code generated from the program) and start using it:

```
//Instead of
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");

//do this
Encoding enc = new ISO88599Encoding();
//Proceed exactly the same
```

The code generated is too long to copypaste here but hopefully you manage with these instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code that is Windows Phone 7.1 (and Silverlight I think) compatible that redefines an ISO-8859-9 (or Latin9) encoding. The code also redefines the ISO-8859-1 (or Latin1) and Windows-1252 for convenience. It could also be used to define the other ISO Latin encoding family:

```
public class Latin9Encoding : LatinEncoding
{
    public Latin9Encoding()
        : base(CharMap)
    {
    }

    static Latin9Encoding()
    {
        CharMap = new Dictionary<byte, char>();
        CharMap.Add(0xD0, '\u011E');
        CharMap.Add(0xDD, '\u0130');
        CharMap.Add(0xDE, '\u015E');
        CharMap.Add(0xF0, '\u011F');
        CharMap.Add(0xFD, '\u0131');
        CharMap.Add(0xFE, '\u015F');
    }

    public static Dictionary<byte, char> CharMap;

    public override string WebName
    {
        get
        {
            return "iso-8859-9";
        }
    }
}

public class Windows1252Encoding : LatinEncoding
{
    public Windows1252Encoding()
        : base(CharMap)
    {
    }

    static Windows1252Encoding()
    {
        CharMap = new Dictionary<byte, char>();
        CharMap.Add(0x80, '\u20AC');
        CharMap.Add(0x82, '\u201A');
        CharMap.Add(0x83, '\u0192');
        CharMap.Add(0x84, '\u201E');
        CharMap.Add(0x85, '\u2026');
        CharMap.Add(0x86, '\u2020');
        CharMap.Add(0x87, '\u2021');
        CharMap.Add(0x88, '\u02C6');
        CharMap.Add(0x89, '\u2030');
        CharMap.Add(0x8A, '\u0160');
        CharMap.Add(0x8B, '\u2039');
        CharMap.Add(0x8C, '\u0152');
        CharMap.Add(0x8E, '\u017D');
        CharMap.Add(0x91, '\u2018');
        CharMap.Add(0x92, '\u2019');
        CharMap.Add(0x93, '\u201C');
        CharMap.Add(0x94, '\u201D');
        CharMap.Add(0x95, '\u2022');
        CharMap.Add(0x96, '\u2013');
        CharMap.Add(0x97, '\u2014');
        CharMap.Add(0x98, '\u02DC');
        CharMap.Add(0x99, '\u2122');
        CharMap.Add(0x9A, '\u0161');
        CharMap.Add(0x9B, '\u203A');
        CharMap.Add(0x9C, '\u0153');
        CharMap.Add(0x9E, '\u017E');
        CharMap.Add(0x9F, '\u0178');
    }

    public static Dictionary<byte, char> CharMap;

    public override string WebName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Windows-1252";
        }
    }
}

public class Latin1Encoding : LatinEncoding
{
    public Latin1Encoding()
        : base(null)
    {
    }

    public override string WebName
    {
        get
        {
            return "iso-8859-1";
        }
    }
}

public abstract class LatinEncoding : Encoding
{
    protected LatinEncoding(Dictionary<byte, char> map)
    {
        FallbackByte = (byte)'?';
        if (map != null)
        {
            Map = map;
            ReverseMap = new Dictionary<char, byte>(map.Count);
            foreach (var entry in map)
            {
                ReverseMap[entry.Value] = entry.Key;
            }
        }
    }

    public byte FallbackByte { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<byte, char> Map { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<char, byte> ReverseMap { get; private set; }

    public override int GetByteCount(char[] chars, int index, int count)
    {
        return count;
    }

    public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
    {
        if (chars == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");

        if (charIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charIndex");

        if (charCount < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charCount");

        if (bytes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");

        if (byteIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteIndex");

        if ((charIndex + charCount) > chars.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charCount");

        if ((byteIndex + charCount) > bytes.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charCount");

        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
        {
            char c = chars[charIndex + i];
            if (ReverseMap != null)
            {
                byte b;
                if (ReverseMap.TryGetValue(c, out b))
                {
                    bytes[byteIndex + i] = b;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            bytes[byteIndex + i] = c > 255 ? FallbackByte : (byte)c;
        }
        return charCount;
    }

    public override int GetCharCount(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
    {
        return count;
    }

    public override int GetChars(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");

        if (chars == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("chars");

        if (byteIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteIndex");

        if (byteCount < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteCount");

        if (charIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charIndex");

        if ((byteIndex + byteCount) > bytes.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteCount");

        if ((charIndex + byteCount) > chars.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteCount");

        for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
        {
            if (Map != null)
            {
                char c;
                if (Map.TryGetValue(bytes[byteIndex + i], out c))
                {
                    chars[charIndex + i] = c;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            chars[charIndex + i] = (char)bytes[byteIndex + i];
        }
        return byteCount;
    }

    public override int GetMaxByteCount(int charCount)
    {
        return charCount;
    }

    public override int GetMaxCharCount(int byteCount)
    {
        return byteCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Guessing from the [turkish] tag, Turkish _is_ important ;)

Comment: Nice job Simon! +1 for the thoroughness.