# Windows Phone RSS Windows-1250 encoding

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, encoding

I'm working on windows phone project, which reads data from rss. This RSS is encoded in windows-1250 and when displaying in app, i get ??? characters instead of š,č etc...
I've been searching for solution...no luck...please help

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: This may help http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator I got this from a similar question posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001506/windows-phone-character-encoding?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: At the end, I asked RSS provider to give me with UTF-8 encoded stream and it is now working. And @John your tutorial is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're using a `WebClient` to download the RSS then you can specify the encoding to use when downloading the data. In your case you can specify `UTF8`.

```
WebClient client = new Webclient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```