# How Can I Solve Windows Phone WebClient Wrong Encoding?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, encoding, windows-phone, webclient

I am creating a Turkish application and I want to make dynamic messages with usingmy domain.

I am editing [this html](http://firsttie.com/example.html) and getting it with WebClient in Windows Phone Application but it is getting Turkish characters wrong. I have tried this,

```
   myWebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

but it hasn't run correctly too. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the tool mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001506/windows-phone-character-encoding to get the encoder.

Comment: Thank you @keyboardP I think it will item that I am searching.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the HttpClient NuGet package, should have improved support for encoding.
http://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClient/