# Special Characters on Windows Phone 8 with StreamReader

Tags: c#, text, windows-phone-8, streamreader

I want to read an txt-file with StreamReader and then give it to TextBlock. The Code is for a Windows Phone App and is in C#:

```
var resource = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("File.txt", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);

while ((line = sreader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   TextBlock.Text = sreader.ReadLine();
}
```

This read all the Text from the file to my TextBlock, but I have special characters in it, like ä or ü or ö and they don't display in the TextBlock. How can I display these characters in my TextBlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader(v=vs.110).aspx) with [encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) - for example UTF8:

```
using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{ 
  while ((line = sreader.ReadLine()) != null)
    TextBlock.Text = sreader.ReadLine();
}
```

Also it's usefull to put your `StreamReader` into `using` as it is `IDisposable`.

---

If you need other Encoding than UTF8 or Unicode, then you can try to use [this program](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) to generate the Encoding.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014124/2681948) you should paste the generated code and then use it for your StreamReader (I've not tried it):

```
Encoding myEncoding = new GeneratedEncoding();
```

And then:

```
using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream, myEncoding))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but with the encoding with UTF8 I also don't have special characters like ä or ü. These are german letters.

Comment: @user3493797 Have you tried also `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`?

Comment: @user3493797 In Silverlight there is only UTF-8 and Unicode, if you need more, you can make class with your Encoding with a little help from [this program](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator).

Comment: When I tried Unicode the TextBlock is empty, so there shows no Text.

Comment: If the program hadn't helped - is there a chance that you can put your file.txt somewhere (or maybe better - simple app)?

Comment: This program is awesome, but is there any documentation how can I use this class?

Comment: @user3493797 I've edited a little answer - I've not tried it, then give me a sign if it worked.